# What characters are safe to not escape with CSS value context?

Tags: java, css, sanitization

I have a string that arrives from the user, and is then inserted into a large CSS block using a CSS parser.

CSS escaping can be done with `\C` (where C is a character), `\HexOfC`  (with a space) or `\6DigitHexOfC`.

Generally, all characters can be escaped safely, and CSS would still run as expected. The following works:

```css
div {
  background: \23 f66;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

However, I still want the CSS properties to be as "clean" as possible, because I want, for example, to be able to view URLs and rules cleanly with the inspector.

---

There are characters which are obviously bad. `{};\*` should all be escaped because they can be used to break from the current rule. I am managing a whitelist (everything gets escaped, except for what's allowed) of characters (as opposed to a blacklist where everything is allowed, except for what's not). The whitelisted characters I currently have is

```
'#', ',', '.', '(', ')', '-', '%', '+', '=', '/', ' ', ':', '\'', '"', '\n', '\r'
```

Are there dangerous characters here? Anything that can be used to break out of a rule and affect the rest of the CSS block. Are there characters which aren't here which would get unneededly escaped? (Alphanumeric characters are not escaped by default).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sanitizing input, you could simply allow elements to be transfered.

Basically a client generated structur file:

```
[
    MyDiv: { # Key
        background: "#FFFFFF" # Element
    }
]
```

In this case you just have to create a File.

Dummy Code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(String key: structure.getKeys()) {
    final List<Element> e = structure.getElements(key);
    sb.append(".") // This may be changed of course
      .append(key) // ID or class based on type above
      .append("{")
      // Append Elements
      .append("}");
}
```

Generating Elements should be easy.

Each element is just

S := element-key : element-value;

Then you'd be able to whitelist special commands too.

If you wish to keep sanitizing, take a look here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner

Comment: How does that help me? What's stopping the user from inserting evil CSS?

Comment: How should he? You can allow/disallow any element you wish, by filtering element-key. div's, element-keys and element-values itself just need to be A-Z, a-z, 0-9, # and ". You avoid advanced filtering if you convert each element by hand.